# Fastest RDP client on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, remote-desktop

OS: WinXP, Win7

According to this [thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20140508195456/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2008/06/25/remote-desktop-connection-terminal-services-client-6-1-for-windows-xp-sp2-x86-platforms.aspx?PageIndex=6#comments) (Bret's comment) and [Quest's EOP](https://web.archive.org/web/20230907003624/https://www.quest.com/). I was wondering besides purchasing EOP, is there any 3rd party RDP client provides better performance (specifically on bandwidth usage)? I know some of them require to install a server on remote host, however, I don't have access to remote host. So just looking for a client-only alternative solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  In order to improve the performance of RDP, you'd need to make changes server-side so that it can send less data over the wire.  Whether that change is software installed on the RDP server or an RDP accelerator device placed between the server and its internet gateway doesn't matter.  The only changes you can make client-side are the ones exposed in MS's Remote Desktop Client.

Comment: It _might_ help to use the latest version of the RDP client. [Here's 7.0 for Windows XP.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=72158b4e-b527-45e4-af24-d02938a95683&displaylang=en)

Comment: Software installed doesn't generally influence RDP performance, and RDP accelerators are rare...

Comment: @afrazier could you elaborate on the server side changes? somebody has asked a question here inspired by your remark in this ^ answer http://superuser.com/questions/347071/fastest-remote-desktop-server-side-on-windows

Comment: @barlop: Thanks for the heads up, but it got closed before I could get to it.  What I'm talking about is either RDP optimizer software like EOP as mentioned in the question or Ericom Blaze, hardware solutions like Riverbed appliances, or flat out replacing RDP with ICA (which is, AFAIK, the only protocol that's consistently faster than RDP).  Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with any of these products.  If you want more information on RDP optimization, a question over at ServerFault may prove worthwhile if one isn't already there.

Answer (score 3):

No, RDP is as fast as it can get, if it's slow for you trim down the options of your connection.